# How do I quit a console app when the "if-requirement" is fulfilled?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am currently working on a check digit calculator for 12-char ISBN numbers and I'm trying to get it to quit if the user puts in a number which is longer than 12 characters.

```
Console.WriteLine("ISBN-Prüfziffer berechnen");
        Console.WriteLine("=========================");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("ISBN-Nummer ohne Prüfziffer: ");
        string ISBNstring = Console.ReadLine();
        ISBNstring = ISBNstring.Replace("-", "");
        ISBNstring = ISBNstring.Replace(" ", "");
        if (ISBNstring.Length > 12)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fehlerhafte Eingabe");
            Console.Read();
            Environment.Exit();
        }

        int Summe = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            int digit = ISBNstring[i] - '0';
            if (i % 2 == 1)
            {
                digit *= 3;
            }
            Summe += digit;
        }
        int PrüfZif = 10 - (Summe % 10);

        Console.Write("Prüfziffer: ");
        Console.Write(PrüfZif);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The way it is now, the application gives out the error message "Fehlerhafte Eingabe" when a, let's say, 13 digit number is put in. But it still gives out the result afterwards.

I want it to stop right there after the error message is displayed, which is why I tried to use Environment.Exit.

Not sure why it's not working. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Try `return;` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where do I put return;? Sorry I am not familiar with the command.

Comment: Instead of `Environment.Exit();`, use `return;`. Basically it will stop executing the current method you're in.

Comment: Oh wow nevermind. That was quick and painless. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help :) I've added it as an answer so this can be marked as resolved.

Comment: `Environment.Exit` [is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) to accept a non optional integer. You aren't passing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from comments, just to signify the question as solved:

> Instead of `Environment.Exit();`, use `return;`. Basically it will stop executing the current method you're in.